# How to set image to a UIButton from inside table view DidSelectRow method?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIButton inside UITableView cell. I want to change image of the button when user tapped any cell and i want it to change from didSelectRow method.
[image]

Here i tried this but not doing anything:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tblDelivery.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DeliveryTypeCell") as! DeliveryTypeCell
        cell.btnRadioSelect.setImage(UIImage(named: "radioButtonChecked"), for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?  What specific problem do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably that you are calling dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. Try using cellForRowAtIndexPath instead . This will give you a reference to the current cell, rather than a reference to a new reusable cell.

So, according to your code above:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let cell = tblDelivery.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! DeliveryTypeCell
    
    cell.btnRadioSelect.setImage(UIImage(named: "radioButtonChecked"), for: .normal)
}
```